# Can we get a general solution to the following system of equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, integral-equations

A system of equations $$\frac{df}{dt}(t)=-txg(t)-x, \frac{dg}{dt}(t)=(1-t)xf(t)+x$$ which was constructured from the integral equation $$ F_t (t,x)= x \int_0^{1-t} (1-s)F(s,x) ds + (1-t)x, $$ This generating function comes from some recurrence relation. Is it possible to get (explicitly written) solutions expressed in terms of familiar functions? I guess it won't be easy because the system of ODEs is not an autonomous, that is, time-dependent. Would you give me any suggestions on this?

Comment: Do $g,f$ depend on $x$ as well?

Comment: Of course, they depend on $x$.

Comment: I see from you notation that $f$ and $g$ do not depend on $x$. So you can take another derivtaive to get: $g''(t) = (1-t)xf'(t)-xf(t) = (1-t)x(-txg(t)-x) - x (g'(t)/((1-t)x -1/(1-t)) $; so you have an ODE of the form: $g''(t)+a(t)g'(t)+b(t)g(t)=0$ which is solvable by Frubenius method.

Comment: Does Frobenius method work for inhomogeneous system of equations? I know the series solution from the recurrence relation $\phi_{n+1}(t)= \int_0^{1-t} (1-s) \phi_{n}(s)ds.$